The difference between past continuous and past perfect continuous
I would like to ask you about the difference between past continuous and past perfect continuous.

When I was sleeping she got home

When I had been sleeping she got home


To me the difference is that 1 shows for sure that I was still in the middle of my sleep when she got home two actions happend at the same time. 2 is tricky, in my opinion, it either means the same thing as 1 or it is also possible that I wasn't engaged in sleeping when she arrived we don't know it may be that I for instance woke up just before she arrived. If my understanding is correct, I think that changing "when" to "while" would make both sentences the same. My second example with "while" would only make sense if  her arrival happened during my sleeping. Please, tell me if I understand the difference right and if switching to "while" leaves my two examples with the same meaning?

When I was had been sleeping ... is ungrammatical.

Didn't notice that "was" I improved my mistake

Even corrected, it's un-idiomatic.

I. Difference between Past Continuous and Past Perfect Continuous
OP's query:

I would like to ask you about the difference between past continuous and past perfect continuous.

When I was sleeping she got home.
When I had been sleeping she got home.


First let's convert these sentences into normal sentences (though the current sentences also mean the same thing) and then see the difference in meaning:
'1. I was sleeping when she arrived home.
'2. I had been sleeping when she arrived home.
Here "she arrived" is relative time reference. These are the two main differences in the implied meaning between the two tenses.

The  Past Continuous speaks about ongoing past events, while the Past Perfect Continuous shows activities that came before another action.
So in Sentence 1 (Past Continuous), sleep continued after her arrival.
Sentence 2 (Past Perfect Continuous) implies that the sleeping stopped before her arrival.
Past Perfect Continuous  tense is used to talk about longer actions in the past before another action in the past.
So Sentence 2 could indicate a longer duration of sleep.

II. Using "before" in place of "when".
We can sometimes use Simple Past instead of Past Perfect. Similarly if we replace "when" with "before" in this sentence we can use Past Continuous instead of Past Perfect Continuous:
I was sleeping before she arrived home.

Or, another way to rephrase this, is that sentence #2 isn't terribly clear or idiomatic. We're making a guess at what it means, and if we've guessed correctly, there could be improvements to its wording. If we've guessed incorrectly, it would need even bigger changes.

Your second example is unidiomatic. If the speaker had already woken up when 'she' arrived, they would say something like "After I had had my sleep...".
If they were still asleep at the time of her arrival, the past perfect continuous requires a time expression. "When I had been sleeping for two hours..."

Why then for instance "I had been cooking when she arrived" is okay without time expression?

'I had been cooking when she arrived' is OK, but NOT 'When I had been cooking she arrived', which is the exact counterpart of your sentence 2.

Oh, thanks I think I get it now. Only one more question. "When I arrived she had been cooking for 2 hours" means that  she was either engaged in cooking at the moment I arrived or it is also possible that she stopped doing it before my arrival for instance took a break. Does the same apply to "when I had been cooking for 2 hours she arrived"  that we have two possible meanings?

On its own it normally means that she was still cooking. If she was taking a break, you would need to mention that in the same sentence, I think.

so" I was cooking and I had been cooking when she arrived" mean the same thing it lasts till she arrives and to show that it stopped before I need to mark it?

We were talking about I had been cooking for two hours when she arrived. I told you that it meant that you were still cooking.  Without for two hours, it could mean that you had stopped cooking. But we are going round in circles here.

@user203412 Please don't use comment sections to ask new questions. Adding a time duration is a different usage. I would say open a separate question about it, except there have been many such; search for them instead.
